# Possible to create team-city user with specific role from cli?

Tags: python, linux, teamcity, command-line-interface

So I searched alot but unable to find anything. I am writing script (open to both bash and python) that'll create user with specific role. Your expertise on this are much appreciated

Comment: hey @JamilSaid just "Project developer" for user that I want/ have to create

Comment: I want to achieve this any other way rather than web-console

what I am giving to script is 3 variables:

`username = "ahsan"
password = "mypassword"
role = "Project developer"`

just found out there is a way by POST" http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/users " any guide on this with example?